# How do you complete zombotany 2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I just bought a minigame pack with the minigame zombotany 2. I am trying to complete the zombotany 2 but can only get past 50%  of the minigame before the zombies overwhelm me. Is there a recommended strategy to complete the minigame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116205/discussion-between-melon-pult-and-a-bakker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing you can apparently not open the guide links.

The trick is to use as few lanes as possible. This can be achieved by using Garlic to force Zombies away from the lanes you got plants on. and then let AoE plants like Gloomshrooms to damage them by placing them just below and above the water.

Alternatively you can also use cattails on water to cover all lanes.

Pumpkin shields in combination with tall nuts also do wonders as long as you try to use as few lanes as possible.

O and before you got enough sun to build the Gloomshrooms/cattails you should use Potato-Mines and squashes to cover the lanes.